# Under what conditions, depending on my particular choice of $f$ and $g$ (other than $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^\infty$) under which $f\cdot g$ is in L^1?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a possibility of a function $f\in L^{1}(\Omega)$ and $g \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ implying that $f\cdot g\in L^{1}(\Omega)$?
At least can you let me know what suitable function space  $g$ is in some other function space other than $L^2$ for the above to hold?

Comment: If you know that $f \cdot g \in L^1$ for **all** $f \in L^1$, then this already implies $g \in L^\infty$. Does that help you? Otherwise, what exactly is your question?

Comment: $f\in C_0$,$f\in BC$...

Comment: PhoemueX...Thanks...I was asking that is it possible for $f$ to be in $L^1$ and $g$ to be in a function space other than $L^{\infty}$ such that the product $f.g$ is in $L^1$?.

Comment: Dirk...Thanks...Did you mean by $C_0$ as the space of continuous functions with compact support or just the space of continuous functions?. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If $g\in L^\infty$, then $f\cdot g\in L^1$ for all $f\in L^1$. However, for a fixed $f\in L^1$ you may have functions $g\notin L^\infty$ with  $f\cdot g\in L^1$.

Let $f(x)=x^{-\alpha}$, $g(x)=(1-x)^{-\beta}$, $0<\alpha,\beta<1$. Then $f,g\in L^1(0,1)$, none of them is bounded, and $f\cdot g\in L^1(0,1)$. Moreover, if $\beta<1/2$ then $g\in L^2(0,1)$.